On proving $L=\bigcup_{\alpha\in\text{Ord}}L_{\alpha}$ is a model of the Axiom of Pairing
In Set Theory, the author defines $L$ by

and goes on to prove that $L$ is a model of $ZF$. I'm confused about the step in proving that $L$ is a model of the Axiom of Pairing. In particular it seems sufficient to me to end the proof below at "$c\in L_{\alpha + 1}$", as that already shows there is a $c\in L$ for which $c=\{a,b\}$. Why do we need to show "$c=\{a,b\}$" is a $\Delta_0$-formula?


To show absoluteness, i.e. so that we know ${a,b}$ means the same thing relative to $L$.

@spaceisdarkgreen Theorem 12.9 states that if $M$ is a transitive class and $\phi$ is a $\Delta_0$-formula, then $\phi^M \iff \phi$. However, it seems to me that when showing $L$ is a model of ZFC we need to show that $\phi^M$ for every axiom $\phi$ of the theory. Thus showing $\phi^M \iff \phi$ is unecessary. What am I missing?

Please don't use images to explain a mathematical problem.

@Sam You need to show that pairing holds in $L$ which means $\forall x,y\in L;\exists z\in L ; (z = {x,y})^L,$ where $z={x,y}$ abbreviates $x\in z\land y\in z\land \forall w\in z(w=x\lor w=y).$ The first part shows $\forall x,y\in L;\exists z\in L; z={x,y},$ which is not exactly what you need. By the fact that $z={x,y}$ is $\Delta_0,$ you can replace $z={x,y}$ with $(z={x,y})^L.$
